# Convergence of two Cauchy Sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose that $a_n$ and $b_n$ are Cauchy sequences, and that $a_n < b_n$ for all n. Prove that $\lim_{x \to \infty}a_n \le \lim_{x \to \infty}b_n$ for all n.

What is the appropriate strategy to prove this statement?

Comment: hint: the $\sup_n a_n\le\inf_n b_n$

Comment: Hmm, thank you for the hint, but the supremum has not been introduced in class yet.

Comment: sooner or latter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $a=\lim a_n>\lim b_n=b$. Then there is a positive integer $M>0$ such that $|a_n-a|<\frac{a-b}{2}$ for all $n>M$, and there is a positive integer $N$ such that $|b_n-b|<\frac{a-b}{2}$ for all $n>N.$

It follows that for all $n>M+N$, we have $a_n>a-\frac{a-b}{2}=\frac{a+b}{2}=b+\frac{a-b}{2}>b_n$, a contradiction.

Comment: Why is it necessary to divide a-b by 2?

Comment: Hmm, and how do we know that $a-\frac{a-b}{2}=b+\frac{a-b}{2}$?

Comment: Just curious, is it a standard trick to divide by 2 in some situations? How do you "see" that this must be done and the inequality wouldn't work without dividing by 2, or with dividing by another number?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT.** First, show that if $(x_n)$ is a convergent (hence Cauchy) sequence of real numbers and $x_n \geq 0$ then $\lim x_n \geq 0$. Then consider the sequence $z_n$ given by $y_n-x_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Proof by contradiction. Suppose $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n > lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n$. Let $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n =L$, and $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n =L'$
Then, for all $\epsilon > 0$ , there exists $N$ such that $|L-a_n| < \epsilon.$ for all $n> N$ So, $L- \epsilon \leq a_n \leq L+ \epsilon$.

Now choose $\epsilon=(L-L')/2$ say, and arrive at a contradiction. (Note that by assumption $L > L'$.)

Comment: You are missing a $b_n$ in the first limit. And I think you mean for all $\epsilon$ there is an $n$ so that...

Comment: @mathematics2x2life: Yes. Thanks.